# Handling concerns about a new role

Tags: professionalism, new-job, recruitment, manager

I have recently joined a new company, x in a software capacity. It is my first week and I have some concerns about my role. My daily duties within the team have certainly not been what I have expected. I do have the original job role specification from the recruiter, comparing my role to the original, they are very different. For example, the spec notes the use of Agile methodology, certain day to day development related tasks, using certain languages and frameworks. In my time here (~ 1 week) I haven’t written a single line of code or witnessed/been a part of any daily standup. I’ve basically been listing bugs in a production application and adding repro steps (not even fixing anything either!).

I have given it enough time at x, as I originally thought that I needed to give the role some time but now I’m sure I need to say something. I just don’t know how to approach my new manager about it. I don’t want to appear rude, or to overstep any boundary. I would like to be respectful but also firm in my assurance that this is not panning out to be the role I applied for. How is it best to approach such a situation?

Comment: Could you elaborate the discrepancies from the recruiters job description to the actual daily duties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have given it enough time at x, as I originally thought that I needed to give the role some time but now I’m sure I need to say something.

Ask the right questions, and they'll quickly lead to a frank conversation if it's not something you're expected to be doing.

> Hi Peter, I've found `x` issue in production - it seems both reasonably simple to solve and non-urgent. As such, it seems like this would be a good first candidate for me to use to push a fix. Could you point me to any documentation around setting up my dev environment, any code style rules I need to be aware of, PR and code review requirements, etc.? Happy to join in the standup so I can present this as work in progress and start to gain an understanding of what other team members are up to.

You're likely to get one of two responses to that - a "Sure, I was wondering about the best way to get you stuck into things, and this seems like a great idea", or "Err, what, you're a tester, that's not your role, you don't touch the code, hand it to John please."

First case, fantastic - second case, you've opened a dialog where you can show your boss the job spec, state that you expect development work as per what you were promised in the job spec, and go from there.

Answer (score 6):

In my view, 1 week is far to early to be making this judgment about the role.

I wouldn't expect you to be writing any code in the first week on a new code base and a system you are not familiar with.  Reviewing and documenting bugs is a good way to get you exposed to the system and to get a feel for the pain points.

If you are going to approach your manager, I would come from the angle of what else can you do to learn the system and understand the team's work.

The one point that I think you could bring up is being invited to the agile meetings.  While you may not have a lot to add to the meetings yet, there is plenty you could learn there by hearing about what is being worked on and what issues exist.